# Fastest way to Compare And Swap (CAS) on Intel x86 CPU?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, latency, cpu-architecture

I need to swap two 8x byte regions of memory, most-likely using `CMPXCHG8B`. However, I want to do this as fast as possible. Other threads will be waiting until this operation is finished. I have a few questions relating to this:

-Is the `LOCK` prefix only required if I am using multiple *processors*, or multiple *cores*? I really want to avoid using this if possible.

-Would I be able to "lock" based on the MESI protocol without using the `LOCK` prefix, if the memory the waiting threads wish to access is in a different cache line?

I am running on a single processor (multiple cores), but answers explaining the difference to a multiprocessor system most-welcome if there's a difference.

Comment: For this discussion, "processor" == "core".

Comment: I don't think `CMPXCHG8B` will help you a lot in this case, because that only swaps registers and memory, not two memory regions. You might be able to rewrite your code so that you only need to swap 2 consecutive pointers, or use a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple processors or multiple cores, and you want synchronized safe access to shared variables, you can't avoid the LOCK.  (Using XCHG doesn't avoid the lock; it is just hidden in the instruction).

Following Jester's hint, I'd be tempted to name your two chunks of memory "Left" and "Right", and use a FLAG to dynamically rename them, e.g.

```
    GetLeft:  if LSB(FLAG)   ; least significant bit
              Read Left
              else Read Right
```

and

```
    GetRight: if LSB(FLAG)
              Read Right
              else Read Left
```

Then the following code will "interchange" them about as quickly as can be done:

```
    SwapLeftAndRight: 
               LOCK INC FLAG   ; flips LSB of flag
```

This eliminates any need for a mutex.  (If your threads are trying to *update* these regions, you'll need the mutex no matter what you do).

If access speed is actually critical, then his hint about swapping two consecutive pointers to LEFT and RIGHT is pretty good.

Comment: Also note that it is possible to swap a pair of 8-byte areas; but they must be consecutive and the CPU must support the `cmpxchg16b` instruction (which is only supported in 64-bit code, and not supported on some of the earlier 64-bit CPUs).